# Can the first sector be recovered and replaced by a spare sector? Will MBR get damaged if that happens?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

MBR is always located at sector 0 on hard drive, but can it actually be offset?

For example if the first physical disk sector is damaged and irrecoverable, what will happen to the drive? Will the controller virtually map another sector instead of the first one or disk is no longer possible to use as boot drive, but only as direct data storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MBR is always located at sector 0 on hard drive, but can it actually be offset?

The MBR is located at *LBA 0* – logical block address. The system firmware doesn't really care about how the drive maps it physically.

> For example if the first physical disk sector is damaged and irrecoverable, what will happen to the drive? Will the controller virtually map another sector instead of the first one or disk is no longer possible to use as boot drive, but only as direct data storage?

If the sector is remapped, then it is remapped *for all purposes.*

Remapping is done by the disk's controller. However, it's not the disk itself that boots the system – the computer's firmware reads that sector, and it is affected by the controller's sector remapping just like any other software would be.

So assuming a BIOS system, the drive would continue to be bootable as long as the sector (i.e. logical block 0) has a valid BIOS bootcode written to it, regardless of where it is physically located.

(UEFI systems usually do not boot from this sector at all, so they would be unaffected anyway. Their boot process starts with the "GPT" partition table at LBA 1.)

Comment: This seems more related to the question. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> MBR is always located at sector 0 on hard drive, but can it actually be offset?

Externally no, internally yes.

> For example if the first physical disk sector is damaged and irrecoverable, what will happen to the drive? Will the controller virtually map another sector instead of the first one

No. There is no "mapping". The drive will return a read error after a couple of read attempts.
This event will affect SMART values: The drive will raise the "pending sector count" by one.

> or disk is no longer possible to use as boot drive, but only as direct data storage?

In such a situation the drive will neither be usable for boot purposes nor as a data drive. That does not include that you store data sector-wise without the use of an operation system.

Once you decide to issue a write request to the first sector (sector 0) the drive will redirect this sector internally to a spare sector. The write command is a signal for the drive that the content is being given up.
Without a write command the next read attempt of this sector might succeed, so a series of failed read attempts is no reason to remap this sector.
If you rewrite the first sector with garbage content, your drive will be physically OK. Any following read attempt to the first sector will succeed.
The only disadvantage here is that the first sector does not contain useful information. So you won't be able to mount the volumes on this disc.

But using a software like Testdisk you have a big chance of the lost information in the MBR being reconstructed. That means, Testdisk will not only write stuff to the first sector (to trigger the remapping process) buth will fill it with useful information that it gathered before.

By the way, the write command to the MBR will then decrease the "pending sector count" by one and increase the "reallocated sector count".

Answer (score 0):

The
[Master boot record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)
first sector contains the Bootstrap code and the Partition table.
So if destroyed, the disk will no longer be bootable.

Some custom BIOS define the first non-damaged sector as the boot sector,
but this is not the general rule.

If the disk firmware has managed to recover and map the sector to one of its
spare reserve sectors, the sector is no longer damaged.

A GPT disk, unlike MBR, has a backup copy of the sector that can be used to recover
its data.

Comment: Note that, in theory, nothing prevents you from copying the MBR to some file or even some other section of the disk (the end?) manually for backup. Of course, in the latter case, you'd have to make sure no partition overlaps that space, or you could lose that backup.

Comment: So, recover is possible, but the disk itself is no longer usable without special hardware?

Comment: Some software like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) can attempt to recover the lost partitions in order to recover the data, but success is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Zekfad Copying the MBR to prevent data loss is kinda like copying your car key to prevent a car accident. It might help, if the car is locked and that's what's going to cause the accident. If what you want is data perennity, nothing beats a backup.

Comment: Zekfad, yes, recovery is possible but the one sector already broken suggests that the disc might be prone for further dammages. Checking SMART values is a recommended strategy followed by a decision if you want to continue using this drive at all or use it for restricted purposes.